# Separation of MassTransit environment in same ASB namespace

Tags: c#, masstransit

We are a couple of devs working on the same .NET 6 + MT project. We only have one ASB namespace at our disposal to use as dev environment (very tedious governance about getting more).

For the queues we can use `IEndpointNameFormatter` to prefix with something to indicate environment.

For the topics we can use `IEntityNameFormatter` for prefixing.

But these dont matter as the full C# namespace is used as an URI for delivering the messages. Therefore i want to be able to prefix the URI to be able to make a clear cut for each developer.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is incorrect. If you replace the interfaces you mentioned with versions that add a prefix for the given environment, there is no overlap. It is done quite frequently, if you search for those interfaces on StackOverflow and other sites, you'll see plenty of examples.